# Cloudwatch JSON filter patern with special character

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using a JSON logger which writes my log level property as "@l", so the payload looks like:

```
{
  "@l" : "Debug"
}
```

I can filter on other properties like this: `{ $.SomethingElse = "Yolo" }`, but I don't know the right  syntax to escape the @ character in Cloudwatch. I know how to do it in other tools like Splunk, but the Amazon documentation is lacking.